# backbone.js and el attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
(function ($) {
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("body"),
  events: {
    "click #add-friend":  "showPrompt",
  },
  showPrompt: function () {
    var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
  }
});
var appview = new AppView;
})(jQuery);
```

1. Can anyone explain me what is `el` here. Is it element?
2. Does the el argument accept object, if so can i pass my custom view
   object where my button or elements need to be added...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes it's a DOM element.
2. No you cannot pass a custom object. You either specify an existing element, or creating one  from the `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties of the view. If you don't specify an element, it defaults to a `div`

It's all in the [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) actually...

Answer (score 2):

Alladnian answered it but I would add that when using `el` you can make use of `$el` which is a cached jQuery object of your view element.

So you can always simply pass only the tag you wish to use (for consistency, brevity and flexibility) and then reference it as `$el` to make use of it as a jQuery object.

```
this.$el.addClass("active");
```